# No persistent data on Firefox OS using ember-localforage-adapter

Tags: ember.js, localforage

I've got an issue with using this adapter.
I'm a noob in Ember, so it might be (and probably is) my error...

Ember 1.13.8
Ember Localforage Adapter 1.13.1

- Adding an entry is fine - adapter is called.
- Adapter isn't called when the application is started.
- Data is missing when an app is reloaded.

https://github.com/zalun/stereophoto/tree/master/ember-stereophoto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `peekAll` to retrieve all the models in your `stereos/index` route but in the adapter of [localforage](https://github.com/genkgo/ember-localforage-adapter/blob/master/addon/adapters/localforage.js) `peekAll` is not overwritten (which means that its behaviour hasn't been changed from its original one in ember-data). You should use `findAll`instead.